# TensfoFlow: Linear Regression loss increasing (instead decreasing) with successive epochs

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning TensorFlow and trying to apply it on a simple linear regression problem. `data` is numpy.ndarray of shape [42x2].

I'm a bit puzzled why after each succesive epoch the loss is increasing. Isn't the loss expected to to go down with each successive epoch!

Here is my code (let me know, if you'd like me to share the output as well!): (Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer to it.)

1) created the placeholders for dependent / independent variables

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='Y')
```

2) created vars for weight, bias, total_loss (after each epoch)

```
w = tf.Variable(0.0,name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(0.0,name='bias')
```

3) defined loss function & optimizer

```
Y_pred = X * w + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y - Y_pred), name = 'loss')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)
```

4) created summary events & event file writer

```
tf.summary.scalar(name = 'weight', tensor = w)
tf.summary.scalar(name = 'bias', tensor = b)
tf.summary.scalar(name = 'loss', tensor = loss)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

evt_file = tf.summary.FileWriter('def_g')
evt_file.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
```

5) and execute all in a session

```
with tf.Session() as sess1:
sess1.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
for epoch in range(10):
    summary, _,l = sess1.run([merged,optimizer,loss],feed_dict={X:data[:,0],Y:data[:,1]})
    evt_file.add_summary(summary,epoch+1)
    evt_file.flush()
    print("  new_loss: {}".format(sess1.run(loss,feed_dict={X:data[:,0],Y:data[:,1]})))
```

Cheers!

Comment: can u post a sample of your data?  At least 10.

Comment: : 20477196.0
  : 8389799424.0
  : 3440635019264.0
  : 1410998762209280.0
  : 5.786483681258373e+17
  : 2.3730280954829e+20
  : 9.731749171431463e+22
  : 3.99097521643995e+25
  : 1.6366924149690585e+28
  : 6.712048633325622e+30

Comment: I notice weight swing b/w -ve and + territory, to very large number: e0: w 0.0, b 0.0 
e1: w 45.9618034362793, b 2.828000068664551 
e2: w -885.352294921875, b -43.586029052734375 
e3: w 17974.052734375, b 906.8658447265625 
e4: w -363946.125, b -18330.419921875 
e5: w 7370275.5, b 371251.5625 
e6: w -149254576.0, b -7518119.0 
e7: w 3022537472.0, b 152248672.0 
e8: w -61209063424.0, b -3083169792.0 
e9: w 1239537811456.0, b 62436925440.0

Comment: Both x and y data?

Comment: [   6.2,   29. ],
       [   9.5,   44. ],
       [  10.5,   36. ],
       [   7.7,   37. ],
       [   8.6,   53. ],
       [  34.1,   68. ],
       [  11. ,   75. ],
       [   6.9,   18. ],
       [   7.3,   31. ],
       [  15.1,   25. ],
       [  29.1,   34. ],
       [   2.2,   14. ],
       [   5.7,   11. ],
       [   2. ,   11. ],
       [   2.5,   22. ],
       [   4. ,   16. ],
       [   5.4,   27. ],
       [   2.2,    9. ],
       [   7.2,   29. ],
       [  15.1,   30. ],
       [  16.5,   40. ],
       [  18.4,   32. ],
       [  36.2,   41. ],

Comment: [  39.7,  147. ],
       [  18.5,   22. ],
       [  23.3,   29. ],
       [  12.2,   46. ],
       [   5.6,   23. ],
       [  21.8,    4. ],
       [  21.6,   31. ],
       [   9. ,   39. ],
       [   3.6,   15. ],
       [   5. ,   32. ],
       [  28.6,   27. ],
       [  17.4,   32. ],
       [  11.3,   34. ],
       [   3.4,   17. ],
       [  11.9,   46. ],
       [  10.5,   42. ],
       [  10.7,   43. ],
       [  10.8,   34. ],
       [   4.8,   19. ]]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that your learning rate is too big.  I was able to get reasonable results by changing it from 0.001 to 0.0001, but I only used the 23 points from your second-last comment (I initially didn't notice your last comment), so using all the data might require an even lower number.

0.001 seems like a really low learning rate.  However, the real problem is that your loss function is using `reduce_sum` instead of `reduce_mean`.  This causes your loss to be a large number, which sends a very strong signal to the GradientDescentOptimizer, so it's overshooting despite the low learning rate.  The problem would only get worse if you added more points to your training data.  So use `reduce_mean` to get the average squared error and your algorithms will be much better behaved.

Comment: Thanks! This seems reasonable. I already upvoted your response, will give it a shot again as per your recommendations and accepted the answer as well!. Thanks again for your time & efforts!

Comment: Thanks a lot for thorough explanation! I understand better now. and your recommendations worked :)